# cannot iterate on a vector

Tags: c++, vector, most-vexing-parse

So, I want to read values from a .txt file, values are pretty simple four float values on the same line. 
I wrote this:

```
int read_calibration () {

  std::ifstream input("floor.txt");
  if (!input.good())
  {
        cout << "floor info file does not exist!" << endl;
    return -1;
  }
  std::vector<float> data(std::istream_iterator<float>(input),
                      std::istream_iterator<float>());

  for (std::vector<float>::iterator it = data.begin() ; it != data.end(); ++it)
    std::cout << ' ' << *it;

  return 0;
}
```

When I build it I get this error:

```
 error: request for member ‘begin’ in ‘data’, which is of non-class type ‘std::vector<float>(std::istream_iterator<float>, std::istream_iterator<float> (*)())’
 for (std::vector<float>::iterator it = data.begin() ; it != data.end(); ++it)
```

I am running on Ubuntu 14.04 using gcc version 4.8.4

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Most_vexing_parse

Comment: @vsoftco: It's not the *most* vexing one; it's just the normal kind of vexing.

Comment: @KerrekSB Is there a difference? ;) I thought it's always called "most vexing".

Comment: For me the *"normal"* is without parameter, and the *most* is with.

Comment: @KerrekSB I think this is the exact case that coined the term "Most vexing parse"

Comment: @vsoftco: I thought most vexing is something like `S s(S())`, where you think you create something value-initialized.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Say this instead:

```
std::vector<float> data(std::istream_iterator<float>(input), {});
```

Your original code isn't defining a variable, but declaring a function.

Answer (score 3):

Most vexing parse :-/

use `{}`

```
std::vector<float> data{std::istream_iterator<float>(input),
                        std::istream_iterator<float>()};
```

or

```
auto data = std::vector<float>(std::istream_iterator<float>(input),
                               std::istream_iterator<float>());
```

Comment: Or parenthesize one of the parameters in case OP cannot use C++11.